# During the network training on Linux, each iteration takes more time to process than the previous iteration. Any ideas why this is?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, training-data

I am quite new in neural networks and also on Linux. I am training a network using Tensorflow wit GPUs. The network requires 50,000 iterations. When I train the network on Windows, each iteration takes same amount of time. The windows system has an old GPU and we shifted to Linux for this training. So, when we run the same network training, without modifying anything, the time to process each iteration increases linearly. Like each iteration takes more time to process than the previous iteration. It seems there is something with Linux that I don't know how to handle. Can anyone please guide me, how can we resolve this issue?

I tried running of windows system and it runs without this issues. I am new on Linux, and don't know what could be the cause. I am adding the code here.

Thanks for your time. Sohaib

```
for i in range(nc['Niters']):
    us_v = np.random.uniform(us_g_range1, us_g_range2)
    if i == 8000:
        lr = lr * 0.1
    if (i+1) % 50000 == 0:
        lr *= 0.1
    if i % 10 == 0:
        feed_test[vn_model.ph_layer_weighting_t] = np.array([cur_w])
        [test_accuracy, reg_c] = sess.run([net_cost, regul_cost], feed_dict = feed_test)
        fvals_test.append(test_accuracy)

    if i% 100 == 0:
        if mat_export_fname:
            dict_mat = vn_model.eval_batch_and_export_by_layer(sess, feed_test)
            dict_mat['fv_train'] = np.array(fvals_train, dtype = np.float32)
            dict_mat['fv_test'] = np.array(fvals_test, dtype = np.float32)
            dict_mat['learning_rate'] = np.array(lr, dtype = np.float32)
            dict_mat['imgs_test'] = imgs_test
            dict_mat['kspc_test'] = kspc_test
            dict_mat['mask_test'] = masks_test
            dict_mat['coil_test'] = coils_test
            dict_mat['cur_w'] = cur_w
            sio.savemat(mat_export_fname, dict_mat)
        if ckpt_fname:
            save_path = saver.save(sess, ckpt_fname)
    if i == 20 and debug_timeline:
        sess.run([train_step, minmax_ops], feed_dict = feed_train, options=options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
        fetched_timeline = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
        chrome_trace = fetched_timeline.generate_chrome_trace_format()
        with open('timeline_03s.json', 'w') as f:
            f.write(chrome_trace)
        print("Timeline generated")
    if nc["ada_interpolation"]:   
        if i > 50:
            if ((i+1) % 20 == 0 and i < 800) or (i+1) % 200 == 0:
                # pass
                vn_model.readjust_interp_resp(sess)
    if nc['n_accum'] == 1:
        kspc_batch, imgs_batch, masks_batch, coils_batch = sample_batch(data, coil_sens, masks_list, n_batch, t_width, z_width,v_width, max_noise = NOISE_LVL, us_v = us_v)
        kspc_batch, imgs_batch, coils_batch, masks_batch, _, _ = vnmodel_flow3dvt_coilsens.data_normalize(kspc_batch, imgs_batch, coils_batch, imsz, masks_batch, nc['dc_norm_type'], nc['nrm_norm_type'])
        feed_train = {ph_img_out : imgs_batch, ph_mask : masks_batch, ph_learning_rate: lr, ph_coils : coils_batch}

        if kspc_batch is not None:
            feed_train[ph_kspc] = kspc_batch
        if nc['train_reg_strength']:
            feed_train[regularization_strength] = np.random.uniform(0.1, 1., n_batch)
        if nc['spatial_weighting']:
            feed_train[ph_weights] = weights_batch
        feed_train[vn_model.ph_layer_weighting_t] = np.array([cur_w])
        ftr, _, _ = sess.run([net_cost, train_step, minmax_ops], feed_dict = feed_train)
    else:
        sess.run(zero_ops)
        for ai in range(nc['n_accum']):
            us_v = np.random.uniform(us_g_range1, us_g_range2)
            kspc_batch, imgs_batch, masks_batch, coils_batch = sample_batch(data, coil_sens, masks_list, n_batch, t_width, z_width,v_width, max_noise = NOISE_LVL, us_v = us_v)
            kspc_batch, imgs_batch, coils_batch, masks_batch, _, _ = vnmodel_flow3dvt_coilsens.data_normalize(kspc_batch, imgs_batch, coils_batch, imsz, masks_batch, nc['dc_norm_type'], nc['nrm_norm_type'])
            feed_train = {ph_kspc : kspc_batch, ph_img_out : imgs_batch, ph_mask : masks_batch, ph_learning_rate: lr,  ph_coils : coils_batch}
            feed_train[vn_model.ph_layer_weighting_t] = np.array([cur_w])
            ftr, _, _ = sess.run([net_cost, accum_ops, minmax_ops], feed_dict = feed_train)
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {ph_learning_rate : lr})

    fvals_train.append(ftr)
```